# Efficient MySQL Searching

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to create a search method where the user can enter one or more words and I return any data that may contains those words.

I have the following query

```
select e.eventName
from events e 
where e.eventName like '%emma%' or
      e.eventId in (select et.eventId from event_tags et where et.tagName like '%emma%');
```

`
This however takes a whopping 33.03 seconds. Is there a more efficient way to search multiple tables using 'like' then? How can I improve this? I found a link to [MySQL BOOLEAN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

is this the prefered method to handle a search for one or more keywords?

Comment: Look into fulltext search instead of using LIKE

Comment: Why are you using `like` and not `=`?

Comment: lol because I'm ignorant :) I'll try this suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.eventName from events e inner join event_tags et on e.eventId=et.eventId and et.tagName like "%emma%"
union
select e2.eventName from events e2 where e2.eventName like "%emma%"
```

It removes the in clause. You can try it

Comment: Thank you blackdog, this did the trick and blazingly fast. Wan xexie. :)